# Workbox Webpack Plugin InjectManifest build errors

Tags: javascript, webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

When attempting to use workbox-webpack-plugin's InjectManifest on version 6.1.5 I get an error:

`ERROR in compilation.fileDependencies.add is not a function`

This is not the case when using GenerateSW and I cannot resolve this issue unless I downgrade to 4.3.1 or remove the package from my project.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue so I can use the latest version?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sorry about that—what version of `webpack` are you using?

Comment: @JeffPosnick I'm using version 4.44.2. Thanks!

Comment: That's very strange, as `webpack` v4.44.2 does have `compilation.fileDependencies.add()` [defined](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.44.2/lib/Compilation.js#L1866) as a `SortableSet` with an `add()` method, and that's the version of `webpack` that we test against. Are you perhaps using an additional plugin in your `webpack` compilation that might be overwriting the `compilation`'s settings?

Comment: It's probably best to open a bug at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues with those details so we can investigate outside of the comments section on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JeffPosnick sounds great thanks!